# What will I lose if I restart my copy of Omega Ruby?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I really want to restart my copy of OR to soft reset for shiny legendaries this time around. The problem is, I'm not sure what exactly I'll lose if I do, and whether it will be worth it just for this.

So should I reset my game?*

<sub>* I already know how to reset / restart my game</sub>

Comment: If you delete/restart your game, what makes you think you'd keep *anything*?

Comment: I wanted to know specifically what would be lost.

Comment: Well, specifically: everything that's stored on your cartridge (except the game itself, naturally).

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, I assume you are talking about deleting your save file and starting the game over from the title screen (B+X+Up, etc).

If so, you lose *everything*. You'll start the game just like you did when you first got it, right out of the box.

This only affects this game, though. If you have Pokemon or items you want to keep around, you can trade them to another game (or use the Pokemon Bank, but not for items) before deleting your old one. Then transfer them back once you get the chance to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's your own choice if you wan't to restart the game. You will lose everything except the game itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent caught the legendaries yet,DONT RESTART THE ENTIRE GAME!Soft reset with Left Trigger and Right Trigger and Start.If you have caught them and want to keep your pokemon,have a trusted person hold them or use pokebank before you reset the game,then play untill you can use wifi.Make a note of how many pokemon you have transfer so you can catch that many zigzagoons.Always have some extra pokeballs if one of them misses.If you use pokebank,i think as soon as you get to the first pokemon center you can transfer them back without catching zigzagoons (i dont have pokebank because i have 2 3ds and both games on 3ds)